# My Java code stops in the middle of execution

Tags: java

My Java project while running stops in the main method even though I have given it accurate redirecting and all that stuff...My code and explanation is below.

```
public class passWord {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Welcome to passGen");
      System.out.println("Please enter password here");
      Scanner passWordScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      String passWordString = passWordScanner.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Checking password strength :-)...");
      passWordStrengthINT(passWordString);
   }

   public static void passWordStrengthINT(String passWordString) {
      double passWordStrengthScore = 0;
      if (passWordString.contains("1")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("2")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("3")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("4")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("5")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("6")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("7")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("8")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("9")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("0")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      passWordStrengthCharS(passWordString, passWordStrengthScore);
   }

   public static void passWordStrengthCharS(String passWordString, double passWordStrengthScore) {
      if (passWordString.contains("a")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("b")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("c")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("d")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("e")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("f")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("g")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("h")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("i")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("j")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("k")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("l")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("m")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("n")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("o")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("p")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("q")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("r")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("s")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("t")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("u")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("v")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("w")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("x")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("y")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("z")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      passWordStrengthL(passWordString, passWordStrengthScore);
   }

   public static void passWordStrengthL(String passWordString, double passWordStrengthScore) {
      if (passWordString.contains("A")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("B")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("C")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("D")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("E")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("F")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("G")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("H")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("I")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("J")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("K")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("L")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("M")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("N")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("O")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("P")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("Q")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("R")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("S")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("T")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("U")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("V")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("W")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("X")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("Y")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("Z")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      passWordStrengthSym(passWordString, passWordStrengthScore);
   }

   public static void passWordStrengthSym(String passWordString, double passWordStrengthScore) {
      if (passWordString.contains("!")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("@")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("#")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("$")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("%")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("^")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("&")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("*")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("(")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains(")")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("_")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("-")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("<")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains(">")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("/")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordString.contains("?")) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.5 * 2;
      }
      passWordLength(passWordString, passWordStrengthScore);
   }

   public static void passWordLength(String passWordString, double passWordStrengthScore) {
      int passWordLength = passWordString.length();
      if (passWordLength > 3 && passWordLength < 5) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore + 0.1 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordLength < 3 && passWordLength > 1) {
         passWordStrengthScore = passWordStrengthScore - 0.1 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordLength < 10 && passWordLength > 5) {
         passWordStrengthScore =+ 0.1 * 2;
      }
      if (passWordLength > 10)  {
         passWordStrengthScore =+ 10 * 2;
      }
      ScoreCheck(passWordStrengthScore, passWordString);
   }

   public static void ScoreCheck(double passWordStrengthScore, String passWordString) {
      if (passWordStrengthScore > 10) {
         decreaseScore(passWordStrengthScore, passWordString);
      } else {
         System.out.println("Your Password Strength Score is " + passWordStrengthScore);
         wordCompliments(passWordStrengthScore, passWordString);
      }
   }

   public static void wordCompliments(double passWordStrengthScore, String passWordString) {
      if (passWordStrengthScore < 3) {
         System.out.println(" Your PassWord " + passWordString + " is WEAK :-(");
      }
      if (passWordStrengthScore > 3 && passWordStrengthScore < 5) {
         System.out.println(" Your PassWord " + passWordString + " is OKAY :-|");
      }
      if (passWordStrengthScore > 5 && passWordStrengthScore < 10) {
         System.out.println(" Your PassWord " + passWordString + " is Good :-|");
      }
      if (passWordStrengthScore == 10) {
         System.out.println(" Your PassWord " + passWordString + " is Excellent and Strong :-D");
      }
   }

   public static void decreaseScore(double passWordStrengthScore, String passWordString) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         if (passWordStrengthScore > 10) {
            passWordStrengthScore--;
         } else {
            ScoreCheck(passWordStrengthScore, passWordString);
            break;
         }
      }
   }

}
```

Pretty big, huh .

**I tried changing the order of methods and tried lightening the code**

I am working on a project in which user gives me their password and I check its strength. My code stops right after  this line of code  `System.out.println("Checking password strength :-)...");`

But I have noticed whenever I input a smaller value my code gets completed. I don't know why...Is there a limit of characters for the string?

Note: I am new to Java, so there is probably a lot to learn, I took this as a personal project :D

Comment: Ever heard of a loop? You are repeating the same code all over. You can check if a character falls within a range instead of 0, 1, 2... Also what happens when someone inputs the same character twice?

Comment: Also, ``+ 0.5 * 2`` is reduced to ``+ 1`` because the multiplication is done before any addition, which is probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to apply this concept instead of all those ifs. Using a loop to check the ASCII code of the character. For example you are now checking the lower case alphabets, hence the ASCII code for lower case alphabet is in range 97 to 122 (https://www.ascii-code.com/). Each time the loop found something between the range it adds to the alphabet count. Next you can assign whatever value to your strength points / letter can calculate the total strength value of the password.

```
String pw = "abcdefg";
    int count = 0;
    double point = 1.5;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < pw.length(); i++){
        if((int)pw.charAt(i) >= 97 && (int)pw.charAt(i) <= 122){
            count++;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Password point: " + count*point);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nah, wait. You need to make sure the statements are separate. or do else-if's and sort the letters by character.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out...But Wait...One else if per if?

Comment: Wait...you'll need a bigger compiler/processer or you will just need to wait for results. There are probably more efficient ways to program this but I don't know them

Answer (score 0):

So, what is happening is that, say for input "abasdak$53lksm" password your *passWordStrengthScore* is coming 20.0, now in this part of code:

```
public static void decreaseScore(double passWordStrengthScore, String passWordString) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     if (passWordStrengthScore > 10) {
        passWordStrengthScore--;
     } else {
        ScoreCheck(passWordStrengthScore, passWordString);
        break;
     }
  }
}
```

When passWordStrengthScore becomes 10, **i becomes 10** in the next iteration, thus the loop fails and your else block is never executed. Hence, you fall back to this code:

```
decreaseScore(passWordStrengthScore, passWordString);
```

and then you just return to main(along the path you came) without printing anything. You can just change the upper limit of for loop from 10 to 11. That should do.